# ordering a linked list in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database that stores records in a linked list that maintains the position of records in the list by storing the previous and next id.

the first record of the list has a previous id of 0 and the last record of the list has a next id of 0.

This database can't be changed.

I want to order the items in the list as they should be presented but was having a lot of trouble working out how to do it.  I tried numerous approaches - like joining the table to itself on next_id = id. i also tried trying to do a `group_concat` on next_ids and ordering by `find_in_set` but didn't get anywhere with that approach either.

here is an sql fiddle with the basic idea. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29b681/2

```
create table tmp (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  prev_id int unsigned  comment 'previous id',
  next_id int unsigned comment 'next id',
  title char(100) comment 'the record',
  primary key (id),
  key prev_id_idx (prev_id),
  key next_id_idx (next_id)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
insert into tmp values (1,0,2,'seq 1'),
(2,1,3,'seq 2'),
(3,2,10,'seq 3'),
(10,3,5,'seq 4'),
(5,10,6,'seq 5'),
(6,5,0,'seq 6');

select * from tmp order by title
```

my question is, how do i order the records so they are presented in order, as defined by the previous and next ids?

Comment: If you have MySQL 8.x, I think you can do this using a recursive CTE. Otherwise I think you need to do it in the application programming language.

Comment: Are you doing it on that table? or there's another source table and the one in question is the end output?

Comment: @FanoFN - doing it on this table. i am current thinking that it needs to be a stored procedure that is running as a recursive function - basically a reducer function that then returns a list of ids as a comma separated list which can be used by find_in_set to show the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is a refactoring of the answer by @FanoFN using FIND_IN_SET, which is slightly easier/shorter. this solution gets away from using prepared statements and concats which are really hard to read/debug.

```
with recursive cte as (
 select id, next_id nextId, cast(id as char(20)) accumulator from tmp where prev_id = 0
 union all
 select tmp.id, tmp.next_id nextId, concat(cte.accumulator,',',tmp.id) accumulator 
  from tmp 
  join cte on cte.nextId = tmp.id
  where tmp.next_id <> 0
 ) select concat(accumulator,',',nextId) orderedIds # add the last id because it will be truncated from the cte
 from cte 
order by length(orderedIds) desc
limit 1
into @orderedIds ;
select * from tmp order by find_in_set(id,@orderedIds)
```

documentation for common table expression (cte) is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive)

This query is essentially a reducer function - and this gets away from that hard to read concat code in the explanation from @fanoFN, and means you don't need to create prepared statements

notes:

1. the cast is required because the first query in a recursive cte has to be the maximum possible length of char - subsequent recursive selects will be truncated if longer. the length of the char cast should be at a minimum the result from `select length(group_concat(id)) from tmp ;` to get an idea what a sane value should be.  it is not possible to set this at runtime with a variable without diving into prepared statements.
2. the cte results don't show the last row - this is because on the last row the next_id = 0, so this has to be `concat`'ed to the accumulator in the select query.
3. ordering by the length is a trick to get the last value in the list because the last item in the list has to have the longest accumulator.
4. you can remove the ordered by and limits to see the results as they come through.
5. in my limited testing, this works for a 1 row linked list (prev_id = 0 and next_id = 0) as well as more rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is something interesting for me. I'm assuming that you're on a newer MySQL version that supports most of the latest functions. Your idea of returning a comma-separated list kind of aligned with my thoughts however I don't think that it's easy to determine the ordering using `FIND_IN_SET`. Although, I could be wrong.

Here's an idea; using [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) function on a converted comma-separated list to a valid JSON array. The first step is to get values in a single row according to the order of `id`=`next_id`. The end result should be:

```
1,2,3,10,5,6
```

This need a multiple `LEFT JOIN` according to the total rows in the table, so 6 rows turn to 5 `LEFT JOINs`:

```
SELECT t1.id, 
               t1.next_id ,
               t2.next_id ,
               t3.next_id ,
               t4.next_id ,
               t5.next_id 
  FROM tmp t1 
   LEFT JOIN tmp t2 ON t1.next_id=t2.id 
   LEFT JOIN tmp t3 ON t2.next_id=t3.id 
   LEFT JOIN tmp t4 ON t3.next_id=t4.id 
   LEFT JOIN tmp t5 ON t4.next_id=t5.id 
   LEFT JOIN tmp t6 ON t5.next_id=t6.id 
WHERE t1.id=1;

Result:
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | next_id | next_id | next_id | next_id | next_id |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 |    2    |    3    |    10   |    5    |    6    |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Next is to convert those comma-separated values to  become a `JSON ARRAY`. I achieved this using a combination of a couple of concatenation method in `SELECT`. Thus:

```
Result:
+------------------------------------+ 
| CONCAT('["',CONCAT_WS('","',t1.id, |
|               t1.next_id ,         |
|               t2.next_id ,         | 
|               t3.next_id ,         |
|               t4.next_id ,         |
|               t5.next_id ),'"]')   |
+------------------------------------+ 
|     ["1","2","3","10","5","6"]     |  <---- this becomes a valid JSON value
+------------------------------------+
```

Then with that, I used a combination of `JSON_TABLE` with `ROW_NUMBER()` function retaining the order from the converted `JSON` value in the end query.

```
SELECT *
 FROM tmp t JOIN
  (SELECT idx,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn
       FROM
        JSON_TABLE(@values,"$[*]"
          COLUMNS(
            idx INT PATH "$"
           )
        ) data) r
  ON t.id=r.idx
ORDER BY rn;
```

Value from the first query I've inserted into `@values` variable before I used it in the final query.

Since the first query depends on how many rows present in the table, it has to be always updated whenever there's a new/removed row of data. To resolve the "dynamic" issue, you probably can generate the first query using prepared statement:

```
SET @sql := NULL;

WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT 1 ctr, COUNT(*) mxct FROM tmp UNION ALL
SELECT ctr+1, mxct FROM cte WHERE ctr+1 <= mxct)
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT CONCAT(\'["\',CONCAT_WS(\'","\',t1.id, ',
         GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('t',c1.ctr,'.next_id ')),
       '),\'"]\') INTO @val FROM tmp t1 ',
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('LEFT JOIN tmp t',c2.ctr,' ON t',c1.ctr,'.next_id=t',c2.ctr,'.id') 
      SEPARATOR ' '),' WHERE t1.id=1;') INTO @sql
FROM cte c1 
 LEFT JOIN cte c2
 ON c1.ctr = c2.ctr-1
WHERE c2.ctr IS NOT NULL;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b91ef0109583a28c5b9bb23f0df7f632)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have a double linked list, please see below example of recursive cte function:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte ( id, prev_id, next_id, title )
 AS
  ( SELECT id, prev_id,next_id,title
      FROM tmp WHERE next_id =0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT tmp.id,tmp.prev_id,tmp.next_id,tmp.title
     FROM cte JOIN tmp ON cte.id = tmp.next_id
   )
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY id;
```

`prev_id` and `next_id` should be referencing the same table with that your table definition should look like this:

```
create table tmp (
id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
prev_id int unsigned reference tmp(id)  comment 'previous id',
next_id int unsigned reference tmp(id) comment 'next id',
title char(100) comment 'the record',
primary key (id),
key prev_id_idx (prev_id),
key next_id_idx (next_id)
);
```

You should also enforce constraint on this columns to be sure that next_id -> next_id.prev_id

Hope i give you an idea how to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks - i can't add constraints because the database can't be changed. Also for some reason they link 0 as the first prev and last next id which would break the constraint.
also your query didn't order correct as requested - when i ran the query it selected ordered by id.